# How to reprogram the key fob for a 2009 Pontiac Montana SV6

Tags: pontiac

I'm looking for the 10 million steps required to reprogram the keyless entry fob for a 2009 Pontiac Montana SV6.

Comment: Do you have an owner's manual? I'd check there first.

Comment: Yeah, it just says that it is possible.

I just broke down and took it to the dealership.  I remember for my Focus, you turn the key in the ignition 3 times, put the signal light to the right, lock the doors, then press the keyless fob buttons all at once (or something like that).  I was hoping there would be something similar for the montana, but I think the dealers have to do them.

Answer (score 1):

No idea if [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_6144178_program-keyless-entry-pontiac.html) works on a 2009, but it's worth a shot.  The programming procedure on some GM vehicles (2006 Cobalt at least) requires a GM Tech 2, which is highly annoying.  Hopefully linked song and dance works for yours.